# Count how often static method is called in Java

Tags: java, methods, count, static

I try to count how often a static method is called and do not know how to do it, since I can not use an instance variable within the static method as far as I know. 
I have the following class:

```
public class Utilities {

     // print how often method was called + specific Value of Object o
     public static void showObject (Object o) {
          System.out.println(counter + ": " + o.toString());
     }
}
```

Printing the objects-values works, but how can I make the counter count? So the result for the following code should look like this:

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
    Object objectA = new Object ("Object A", 4);
    Object objectB = new Object ("Object B", 4);
    Object objectC = new Object ("Object C", 4);

    Utilities.showObject(objectB);
    Utilities.showObject(objectC);
    Utilities.showObject(objectC);
    Utilities.showObject(objectA);


1: 3.6
2: 8.0
3: 8.0
4: 9.2
```

Greetings and thanks,
Patrick

Comment: what about a static variable? To easy?

Comment: you mean a static variable inside the main-method? 
I thought about this, but the problem is that i have 4 different files (4 different classes) which are all allowed to use the showObject-method. 
so i wanted to increment the counter inside the showObject-method to make sure it counts up whenever it is called. 
A static variable inside the showObject-Method would "die" when the method reaches the end, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to create a static variable outside of the static method:

```
private static int counter = 0;
```

When the method is called, increment the variable:

```
public static void showObject(Object o){
    System.out.println(counter + ": " + o);
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable to count the number of times the  method is called.

```
public class Utilities {

     private static int count;

     public static void showObject (Object o) {
          System.out.println(counter + ": " + o.toString());
          count++;
     }

     // method to retrieve the count
     public int getCount() {
         return count;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add static counter to your class:

```
public class Utilities {

     // counter where you can store info
     // how many times method was called
     private static int showObjectCounter = 0;

     public static void showObject (Object o) {
          // your code

          // increment counter (add "1" to current value")
          showObjectCounter++;
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean

Answer (score 1):

> I can not use an instance variable within the static method as far as I know.

True, but fields can be static as well.

```
class Utilities {

    private static int counter;

    public static void showObject (Object o) {
        System.out.println(++counter + ": " + o.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
private static final AtomicInteger callCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

and then in your method:

```
 public static void showObject (Object o) {
      System.out.println(callCount.incrementAndGet() + ": " + o.toString());
 }
```

Using `AtomicInteger` makes the counter thread-safe.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Utilities {
     static int counter = 0; // when the method is called counter++
     public static void main (String[] args) {
               showObject(null);
               showObject(null); //it is probably a very bad idea to use null but this is an example
               System.out.println(counter);
     }
     public static void showObject (Object o) {
          System.out.println(counter + ": " + o.toString());
          counter++; // method was called. Add one.
     }
}
```